# R run old version from command OSX

Tags: r, macos, backwards-compatibility, rserve

I've got an application that relies on R for some scientific calculations. It is installed in OS X and R is in its default location (`/Library/Frameworks/R.framework`).

The application needs to start Rserve (R CMD Rserve).

This runs `/usr/local/bin/R` (which is a script that does various things) and everything works fine.

However, when the user installs a new version of R, (R CMD Rserve) references to the new R version which has not the required packaged installed and may not work due to compatibility issues.

How can I start Rserve in the correct version of R?

I know that I can change all the `symlink` that link to the current R version in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework`, however, I don't want to change the R version globally. Just my application should use the old version..

Comment: Okay, I found out that every version of R contains its own start script in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/<<version>>/Resources/bin/R`. However, this script defaults the `R_HOME` to `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources` which is in the symlink to the newest R version. Which is stupid.

Comment: Not really stupid, see R Mac FAQ 10.10, but if you want to use that version without changing the symlink, then you can change `R_HOME` to the versioned path in the `R` shell script and cross your fingers.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek Thank you, I solved it by copying the shell script of the required version and changing the R_HOME path to the versioned path. I now run all R commands over this copied shell script. Works fine for now. The future will show if it breaks when new R versions arrive..